# MYSQL using REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

This is the `table`:

```
ID | Amount
---|---
0  | 1,2,3
1  | 11,12,13
2  | 21,23
3  | 2,3
```

The cells may have any number of any numbers delimited by a comma. I need to select rows that have an **Amount** of 2 in them. Since MYSQL REGEXP does not support lookaheads/lookbehinds, I am after a proper regex expression to achieve this. If there is a more efficient solution rather than regex, I'm open to suggestions.

A noob way of achieving this is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
(Amount LIKE '2' OR Amount LIKE '%,2' OR Amount LIKE '2,%' OR Amount LIKE '%,2,%)
```

, but I'd rather avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [**`FIND_IN_SET()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) here:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', Amount) > 0
```

`FIND_IN_SET()` searches for the first parameter in a CSV list as the second parameter.  It handles the mess of trying to sift through commas to find data.  That being said, you should generally avoid using CSV in your tables for the very reason that it makes querying difficult and performance suboptimal.  It would be better to normalize your table have each amount in a separate record associated with a given `ID`.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: This is great! When I designed the table with delimited Amount values, I didn't realise I was making my life so much easier using FIND_IN_SET(). Thanks for pointing it out! So, what you are saying is that it is more efficient to have potentially 10-15 times bigger table, but with unique Amount values, rather than queueing up the Amounts in a single cell? And given the table has thousands of rows, which would work faster - FIND_IN_SET() or the 4 LIKE queries as in my question?